# Serializing/deserializing objects to/from JSON on Toit language

Tags: json, toit

I've a few questions about using json. I can see that there are corresponding modules in the attached library l**ib_v1.0.2**, but the examples do not use them. Is it possible to give two simple examples: *serializing* an object into a json string and *deserializing* json into the same object: for example object's creation via *constructor.json jsonString*. If possible, in addition to serializing/deserializing ordinary fields: **strings, int, bool**, explain how to serialize/deserialize & **hash maps** & **lists** if object contains them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: the encoder now takes a `converter` block which is invoked for objects it doesn't know how to serialize. The `converter` is supposed to convert that object into something the encoder understands.

Currently, the JSON library only supports a hardcoded list of types:

```
  encode obj:
    if obj is string: encode_string_ obj
    else if obj is num: encode_number_ obj
    else if identical obj true: encode_true_
    else if identical obj false: encode_false_
    else if identical obj null: encode_null_
    else if obj is Map: encode_map_ obj
    else if obj is List: encode_list_ obj
    else: throw "INVALID_JSON_OBJECT"
```

This means that it can't serialize/deserialize objects of other (user-defined) types.

I have filed a feature request here: https://github.com/toitware/public/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet tested the deserialization of complex json objects, but apparently Toit supports serialization/deserialization of containers, includes nested ones.
For example a list:

```
import encoding.json as json

main :
  list := [1,2,"covid-19",25,[11,12,"toit",13,14],{"fortran":[77,90]}]
  a1 := list[0]
  log("a1->$a1")
  a2 := list[1]
  log("a2->$a2")
  a3 := list[2]
  log("a3->$a3")
  a4 := list[3]
  log("a4->$a4")
  a5 := list[4]
  log("a5->$a5")
  a6 := list[5]
  log("a5->$a6")

  jsonObjList := json.encode list
  log("jsonObjList($list)")
  
  listClone := json.decode jsonObjList
  log("listClone->($list)")

  aa1 := listClone[0]
  log("aa1->$aa1")
  aa2 := listClone[1]
  log("aa2->$aa2")
  aa3 := listClone[2]
  log("aa3->$aa3")
  aa4 := listClone[3]
  log("aa4->$aa4")
  aa5 := listClone[4]
  log("aa5->$aa5")
  aa6 := listClone[5]
  log("aa5->$aa6")

  jsonObjListText := jsonObjList.to_string
  log("jsonObjListText-> $jsonObjListText")
  
  listClone2 := json.decode jsonObjListText.to_byte_array
  log("listClone2->($listClone2)")

  aaa1 := listClone2[0]
  log("aaa1->$aaa1")
  aaa2 := listClone2[1]
  log("aaa2->$aaa2")
  aaa3 := listClone2[2]
  log("aaa3->$aaa3")
  aaa4 := listClone2[3]
  log("aaa4->$aaa4")
  aaa5 := listClone2[4]
  log("aaa5->$aaa5")
  aaa6 := listClone2[5]
  log("aaa6->$aaa6")
```

Output:

```
michael_k@michaelk:~/toit_apps/json$ toit execute test_json.toit
a1->1
a2->2
a3->covid-19
a4->25
a5->[11, 12, toit, 13, 14]
a5->{fortran: [77, 90]}
jsonObjList([1, 2, covid-19, 25, [11, 12, toit, 13, 14], {fortran: [77, 90]}])
listClone->([1, 2, covid-19, 25, [11, 12, toit, 13, 14], {fortran: [77, 90]}])
aa1->1
aa2->2
aa3->covid-19
aa4->25
aa5->[11, 12, toit, 13, 14]
aa5->{fortran: [77, 90]}
jsonObjListText-> [1,2,"covid-19",25,[11,12,"toit",13,14],{"fortran":[77,90]}]
listClone2->([1, 2, covid-19, 25, [11, 12, toit, 13, 14], {fortran: [77, 90]}])
aaa1->1
aaa2->2
aaa3->covid-19
aaa4->25
aaa5->[11, 12, toit, 13, 14]
aaa6->{fortran: [77, 90]}
michael_k@michaelk:~/toit_apps/json$
```